# Swiper coverflow blank when in Div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

Let me prefix that I'm not very skilled nor know many good practices, I'm learning by doing as projects come about.

I'm using Swiper for a game list slider, but when its put inside another Div it just disappears. I can position and size it correctly outside the Div, but I can't make it responsive that way and its very unorganized.

Below is the section, with the schedule to be on the left and the game slider to be on the right. When outside of the Games Div it will show, but when inside the Div it entirely disappears.

[image: Here is an example of it working when the slider is outside of the div]

```
        <!-- Start of schedule container -->
    <div id="info-wrapper">
        <section id="info">
            <div id="schedule" class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1 id="title"> Stream Schedule</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div id="dates" class="col">
                        <h1> Mondays </h1></div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <p>9:00 - 10:00 PM </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div id="dates" class="col">
                        <h1> Tuesdays </h1></div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <p>9:00 - 10:00 PM </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div id="dates" class="col">
                        <h1> Wednesdays </h1></div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <p>9:00 - 10:00 PM </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div id="dates" class="col">
                        <h1> Thursdays </h1></div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <p>9:00 - 10:00 PM </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div id="dates" class="col">
                        <h1> Fridays </h1></div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <p>9:00 - 10:00 PM </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Container for game list -->
            <div id="games" class="container">
              <h1 id="title"> What I've been playing </h1> 

            <div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(assets/images/box-art/fortnite.png);"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(assets/images/box-art/fortnite.png);"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(assets/images/box-art/fortnite.png);"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(assets/images/box-art/fortnite.png);"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(assets/images/box-art/fortnite.png);"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(assets/images/box-art/fortnite.png);"></div>

                </div>
                <!-- Add Pagination -->
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
    </div>

    </section>
```

Full CSS below for main stylesheet. All other styles for Swiper can be found at http://idangero.us/swiper/

```css
body, html {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
}
 body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 100%;
     line-height: 1.25em;
     font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
 a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: inherit;
}
 .clear:after, .clear:before, .container:after, .container:before {
     content: "";
     display: table;
}
 .clear:after, .container:after {
     clear: both;
}
 .clear, .container {
     zoom: 1;
}
 #header ul #nav li a:hover, .accent, .btn:hover {
     background: #rgba(62, 24, 82, 1);
     color: #fff;
}
 .forum {
     padding: 3px 8px 4px 8px !important;
}
 .btn:hover {
     border-color: #6246a3;
}
 .container {
     padding: 0 3%;
}
 #header {
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 100;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 40px 35px;
}
 #header #displayname {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-size: 137%;
     font-weight: 600;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
 .label {
     font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 54%;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     padding: 0 8px;
     border-radius: 1em;
     -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
     -moz-border-radius: 1em;
     white-space: nowrap;
     vertical-align: middle;
     font-weight: 700;
     margin-top: -4px;
     display: inline-block;
}
 #header ul#nav {
     margin: 2px 0 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 #header ul#nav li {
     display: inline-block;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: 120%;
}
 #header ul#nav li a {
     padding: 3px 8px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
     -moz-border-radius: 100px;
     transition: background .3s ease;
     outline: none;
}
 #content {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 132px 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: table;
     text-align: center;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
 #content .container {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
 .avatar {
     border-radius: 50%;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     margin-bottom: 25px;
     width: 145px;
     height: 145px;
}
 .name {
     color: #eee;
     font-size: 104%;
     font-weight: 600;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     margin: 0 0 7px;
     line-height: 1.5em;
}
 .status {
     font-size: 220%;
     line-height: 1.3em;
     font-weight: 300;
     letter-spacing: 0;
     margin: 0 0 20px;
}
 .btn {
     padding: 15px 24px;
     border: 1px solid #FFF;
     border-radius: 30px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
     -moz-border-radius: 30px;
     font-size: 100%;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     font-weight: 700;
     white-space: nowrap;
     vertical-align: middle;
     display: inline-block;
     transition: background ease .3s;
}
 .live {
     background: rgba(62, 24, 82, 1);
     border: none;
     -webkit-animation: pulse 2s infinite;
     -moz-animation: pulse 2s infinite;
     -o-animation: pulse 2s infinite;
     animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
 .label .live-status {
     font-size: 20px;
     line-height: 19px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin-right: 3px;
}
 #footer {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 100;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 14px 30px;
}
 #footer p {
     font-size: 80%;
     color: #FFF;
     font-weight: 600;
     opacity: .4;
     transition: opacity ease .3s;
     line-height: 1em;
}
 #footer p:hover {
     opacity: .8;
}
 #footer .left {
     float: left;
}
 #footer .right {
     float: right;
}
 @media (min-width: 801px) {
     #header #displayname {
         float: left;
    }
     #header ul#nav {
         float: right;
    }
     #header ul#nav li {
         margin-left: 21px;
    }
}
 @media (max-width: 800px) {
     #header {
         padding: 24px 20px 20px;
    }
     #header #displayname {
         text-align: center;
    }
     #header ul#nav {
         margin: 20px auto 0;
         text-align: center;
    }
     #header ul#nav li {
         margin: 0 4px 12px;
    }
}
 @media (max-width: 750px) {
     .name {
         font-size: 100%;
    }
     .status {
         font-size: 200%;
    }
     .btn {
         width: 80%;
    }
     .avatar {
         width: 120px;
         height: 120px;
    }
     #footer p {
         font-size: 60%;
         padding: 0px 0px;
    }
     .accent, .btn:hover, #header ul#nav li a:hover {
         background: #330066;
    }
     .btn:hover {
         border-color: #330066;
    }
     .live {
         background: #330066;
         border: none;
    }
     @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
         from {
             opacity: 1.0;
             -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #330066;
        }
         50% {
             opacity: 0.8;
             -webkit-box-shadow: none;
             0 0 0px #330066;
        }
         to {
             opacity: 1.0;
             -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #330066;
        }
    }
     @-moz-keyframes pulse {
         from {
             opacity: 1.0;
             -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #330066;
        }
         50% {
             opacity: 0.8;
             -moz-box-shadow: none;
             0 0 0px #330066;
        }
         to {
             opacity: 1.0;
             -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #330066;
        }
    }
     @-o-keyframes pulse {
         from {
             opacity: 1.0;
             -o-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #330066;
        }
         50% {
             opacity: 0.8;
             -o-box-shadow: none;
             0 0 0px #330066;
        }
         to {
             opacity: 1.0;
             -o-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #330066;
        }
    }
     @keyframes pulse {
         from {
             opacity: 1.0;
             box-shadow: 0 0 15px #330066;
        }
         50% {
             opacity: 0.8;
             box-shadow: none;
             0 0 0px #330066;
        }
         to {
             opacity: 1.0;
             box-shadow: 0 0 15px #330066;
        }
    }
}
 #content {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 
}
 #live {
     background: url("http://www.tokkoro.com/picsup/2860789-batman-the-dark-knight-joker-messenjahmatt___movie-wallpapers.jpg") no-repeat center center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     height: 100vh;
}
 #info-wrapper {
     background: url("../img/cell.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}
 #info {
     height: 60vh;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     background-color: rgba(39, 0, 59, .8);
     background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 #schedule {
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
     display: inline-flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     width: 30vh;
     height: auto;
     float: left;
}
 #dates {
     font-size: 80%;
}
 #dates .p {
     font-size: 100%;
}
/* Games Section Wrapper */
 .swiper-container {
     width: 50%;
     height: 50%;
}
 .swiper-slide {
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 18px;
     background: #fff;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-pack: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
     -webkit-justify-content: center;
     justify-content: center;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
     -webkit-align-items: center;
     align-items: center;
}
 #title {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 150%;
     font-weight: 600;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
}
 .col-xs-5ths, .col-sm-5ths, .col-md-5ths, .col-lg-5ths {
     position: relative;
     min-height: 1px;
     padding-right: 15px;
     padding-left: 15px;
}
 .col-xs-5ths {
     width: 20%;
     float: left;
}
/* Pulse Animations Min */
 @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
     from {
         opacity: 1;
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #6246a3;
    }
     50% {
         opacity: .8;
         -webkit-box-shadow: none;
         : 0 0 0 #6246a3;
    }
     to {
         opacity: 1;
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #6246a3;
    }
}
 @-moz-keyframes pulse {
     from {
         opacity: 1;
         -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #6246a3;
    }
     50% {
         opacity: .8;
         -moz-box-shadow: none;
         : 0 0 0 #6246a3;
    }
     to {
         opacity: 1;
         -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #6246a3;
    }
}
 @-o-keyframes pulse {
     from {
         opacity: 1;
         -o-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #6246a3;
    }
     50% {
         opacity: .8;
         -o-box-shadow: none;
         : 0 0 0 #6246a3;
    }
     to {
         opacity: 1;
         -o-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #6246a3;
    }
}
 @keyframes pulse {
     from {
         opacity: 1;
         box-shadow: 0 0 12px #6246a3;
    }
     50% {
         opacity: .8;
         box-shadow: none;
         : 0 0 0 #6246a3;
    }
     to {
         opacity: 1;
         box-shadow: 0 0 12px #6246a3;
    }
}
/* Querying additional screen sizes. */
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .col-sm-5ths {
         width: 20%;
         float: left;
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .col-md-5ths {
         width: 20%;
         float: left;
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .col-lg-5ths {
         width: 20%;
         float: left;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I'm lacking any more information here and I'll update! Scratching my head with this, so thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: can you show it in fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/241hn9kp/

So much isn't hosted, unfortunately so I feel its going to be all kinds of broken in fiddle, but hopefully this can help a bit. Thanks for your response!

Comment: That contains all the code, however, in Fiddle its not going to function by any means unfortunately.

Comment: You did not add swiper js and css but i added now.
https://jsfiddle.net/241hn9kp/1/

Comment: Thank you! Apologies for oversights, I've been at this all night & fairly defeated, just wanted to get this post up to have some guidance to go on when I approach in the AM!

Comment: It disappears if Swiper is placed into the Games Div.

Is there a more appropriate way to nest it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS:

```
#games{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Well I have since called it a night from my PC, however remoted in and quickly added it and it didn't break, so I'll touch on this in the morning and report back!

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: This worked brilliantly, exhaustion causes some oversights. Messed around with it for about 15 minutes this morning and working great and fully responsive, thank you.